# Batch script IF ELSE type command

Tags: batch-file

I'm batch script beginner and here is my code...

```
SQLCMD -E -S DevSSRS01 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_CustAddress WHERE ZipCode = ''" goto :end
```

`if ZipCode =''` no record return, I would like to `goto :end` without further task, but if `ZipCode =''` return with some records I would like to do some tasks before it exit.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the console output of a program in batch scripts using the for command. From `help for`:

> FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ('command') DO command [command-parameters]

In this case, best add `-h -1` to the `sqlcmd` command line, to suppress the column headers. Try the following in your batch script (I only tested a simplified version using `SELECT 0 AS foo`):

```
for /f %%a in ('SQLCMD -E -S DevSSRS01 -h -1 -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl_CustAddress WHERE ZipCode = ''"') do if "%%a" == "0" goto :end
```